# Prime factors of $n!+1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Is it true that for all suficiently large positive integers $n$, the number $N=n!+1$ has a prime factor greater than $n^2?$

If we cannot get a quadratic bound for its largest prime factor, then probably there exists an $\varepsilon>0$, such that $N$ has a prime factor greater than $n^{1+\varepsilon}$ for all $n$ large enough.

Comment: "A conjecture on the prime factorization of n! + 1" by William Gerst on September 13, 2018.
Abstract : In this paper, we state a conjecture on the prime factorization of
numbers of the form n!+1, explore its implications, and compare it with
empirical evidence and established results based on the abc conjecture.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.07360.pdf?

Comment: I do not think that we are able to prove this, but considering the rareness of smooth numbers, there will be only a few $n$ for which no such prime factor exists.